# Weird behaviour with Keras training and 'model is not defined

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am training a stacked LSTM to classify text into a collection of different labels using Tensorflow Keras, but I am running into an odd issue regarding training. [output after trying to train](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYg08.png)

I am not sure why the code runs without error, yet the model has not been trained. Furthermore, when I try to evaluate the model, `test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(val_ds)`, I get `name 'model' is not defined` .

Not sure why this is happening. Any suggestions? The link to the file is https://github.com/tkowalski9938/Maureen-Crops.-Message-Predictor/blob/master/model.ipynb . Thanks for the help

Comment: The number next to the cells is the execution order. It clearly shows that you executed the cells in the wrong order. Note that the notebook state is lost if you stop the Jupyter server.

Comment: Yes, I suspected it might have been that so I have already tried executing sequentially; the issue I described occurs while executing sequentially

Comment: have you tried turning it off and on again